# Незапускается Mysql на vps

Tags: mysql, vps

Незапускается Mysql на vps при перезапуске
Останавливаю майскюл через

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

После этого пытаюсь запустить

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Однако ответ почти всегда Fail. Попробывал так

```
sh -x /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Нашел такое:

> error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)' Check that mysqld is running and
>   that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!

Попробовал решить проблему по этому методу: http://ubuntulinux.ru/config/admin/reshenie-problemy-varrunmysqldmysqld-sock-ne-najden/
но не помогло, прошу помочь создавал сокет вручную, но он после этого почему то после попытки запуска сам удаляется...

Answer (score 1):

Если что-то идет не так, в первую очередь нужно смотреть логи MySQL. В Ubuntu они расположены по пути

```
/var/log/mysql.err
/var/log/mysql.log
/var/log/mysql/error.log
```

Там можно обнаружить больше информации о том, почему MySQL не может стартовать.